# Finding cosets of a linear code given generator matrix

Tags: coding-theory

I’m confused as to how to approach the following problem:

> Let $C$ be a $7$-ary linear code with generator matrix
>   $$ \left[
> \begin{matrix}
> 0 & 1 & 5 & 5 & 0 \\
> 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
> 0 & 6 & 3 & 2 & 1
> \end{matrix} \right]$$
>   What are the cosets of $C$?

I don’t really understand how to obtain the cosets of the code, though I understand what cosets are in general. What am I missing?

Comment: It is just like the cosets of a subspace, or a subgroup (of an abelian group). Here $C$ is a subgroup/space of the ambient space $\Bbb{F}_7^5$ of all $5$-tuples of the 7-ary alphabet.

Comment: Are you sure that the first column of the generator matrix is all zeroes?

Comment: @DilipSarwate That’s what I was given.